# Stop Scrolling in UIWebview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I need to know how to stop scrolling in a UIwebview in xcode 4?

```
[[[webView subviews] lastobject] setScrollingEnabled:NO];
```

The above code does not work because "NSarray" for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'lastobject'. Why is this or is there new code I am unaware of to disable scrolling? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UIView* row = nil;
for(row in webView.subviews){
    if([row isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class] ]){
        UIScrollView* scrollRow = (UIScrollView*) row;
        scrollRow.scrollEnabled = NO;
        scrollRow.bounces = NO;
        scrollRow.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    }
}
```

your code is trying to make assumptions about the order of the subviews that Apple is defining..

Answer (score 5):

Note that with iOS 5 you have direct access to the scroll view.

So if you wanted to maintain compatibility you could do this:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = nil;
if ([webView respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollView)]) { //iOS 5+
    scrollView = webView.scrollView;
} else { //iOS 4-
    for(UIView *view in webView.subviews){
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class] ]){
            scrollView = (UIScrollView *) view;
            break;
        }
    }
}
scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
scrollView.bounces = NO;
scrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply add this line to `viewDidLoad`:

```
myWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would set the webview's `UserInteractionEnabled` property to `NO` so that it cannot be scrolled.

Comment: Instead you loose some other functionality, that might be useful. So this is not a good idea, if you only want to disable scrolling.